# Static Images are not loaded on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating a project on react native and I'm trying to load an static image on my device like:

```
<Image source={require('../components/assets/img/onboarding-devices.png')} style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: null,
          height: null
        }} />
```

It is not loading on the Android device and I don't know why. However, the image loads on some android devices but mine not.

Can anybody tell me why this image loads on some devices and others don't

Thanks!